# Implementation of automated workflow testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, integration-testing

I have doubts on how to implement test automation in the company where I am currently. I was wondering what workflow do you suggest?

The project I will be working on uses, on its back-end, the Java language. At first, I want to propose the use of Selenium Webdriver with Java, but some gaps remain:

1. How would I integrate with problem tracking tools? (Mantis or Jira)
2. A team member suggested using Python with Selenium Webdriver, is it interesting? (I am afraid)
3. When developers are committed to the QA environment, how would I do automated testing automatically?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the evolution of *AUT (Application under Test)* the project is sure to scale up vertically and horizontally. Hence to maintain a healthy *Test Coverage* you have to set up an *Automation Test Suite* to validate the *Regression Tests*.

**Mantis** and **Jira** both can be integrated using either of the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) clients *Java* and *Python* on demand.

While for *Java* clients [testng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56769978/testng-no-tests-found-nothing-was-run-while-executing-automated-tests-using-s/56770108#56770108) is a popular framework, for *Python* clients you can use the [unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859370/python-webdriver-no-browser-launched-while-using-unittest-module/49860022#49860022) framework.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Which tool would you recommend for us to track metrics, resolved issues, amount of test that didn't pass, ...?

Comment: @IagoFrota Sounds like a different question all together. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.