# TestCases not found

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, testng

Code trials:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/hp/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
}

@Test

public void verifyTitle() {
    System.out.println("demo");
    String title =driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("the page title is :"+title);
    Assert.assertEquals(title,"Google");    
}

@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

This is the code I am trying to run using Selenium Testng but showing error as *Test case not found*

Comment: Update the question with entire error stack trace.

Comment: Also how you are running your test, using testng.xml 
Are you getting this option run as testng test for this class in your code ? Also check testng plugin is installed or not

Answer (score 0):

As you are using [*TestNG*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56770108/7429447) you need to add the following import:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

Comment: yes i added also given anotation